# Is there a tutorial for using tensorflow object detection API for training object and key point detection?

Tags: tensorflow, object, key, detection, point

This [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_object_detection) provides a Google Colab notebook for inference of CenterNet HourGlass104 Keypoints 512x512 for object detection and pose key point detection.  Is there a similar notebook or tutorial to train object detection and key point detection on custom datasets?

Comment: You will find everything you need in this documentation: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I only see posts on inferring keypoint locations from pre-trained models.  How to train them on custom data?  I don't see a tutorial or guide for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a detailed github repo [Custom Keypoint Detection](https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/Custom-keypoint-detection) for dataset preparation, model training and inference on **Centernet-hourglass104** keypoint detection model based on **Tensorflow Object detection API** with examples.

This could help you in training your keypoint detection model on custom dataset.

Any issues related to the project can be raised in the github itself and doubts can be cleared here.